# Web Flow + JSF integration default page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, web.xml, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I use Web Flow and JSF, so they works well actually. But I am trying to find out alternative way for set default page different from redirecting on index.html.

The main problem is web analytics scripts don't work properly. I can't track user source fore home page.

The application run on Tomcat 8

Web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=web/home-page">
    </head>
</html>
```

**UPDATE :**

I replace index.html with index.jsp and I set response status as 301. At least it works for google analytics, so I'll check it out for other analytics tools.
But this solution still did not satisfy me.

Web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

index.jsp

```
<%
response.setStatus(301);
String path=(String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
if(path==null){
    path="web/home-page";
}
response.setHeader( "Location", path);
response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
%>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Web Flow, but why can't you just specify the desired file in `welcome-file`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it cannot be used like JSF the expression and the other functions don't work. It isn't rendered just is simple HTML.

Comment: @erdoganonur Are you using spring security project?

Comment: Yes I am using sprin security 3.2.4 and web flow 2.4.0

Comment: @erdoganonur Yea your viewframe work is not aware of how to resolve the welcome file. I was going to suggest to use spring security project to handle routing of requests to substitute the function of the welcome-file. That way any redirection to any view conducted by spring security will get picked up by your view framework in this case JSF. Spring security project is quite modular in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

I would use spring security project instead of welcome files because JSF (or any view framework) is not aware how to resolve a view in welcome-file that is why your logic is not executing.

A possible solution is if you are using the spring security project. Add the following to your security config

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<!--- config omitted for brevity -->
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/index.jsp"/>
</security:http>
```

Again this is just a sample. You can also use other means to define rules. It is quite modular

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" ....
```

Moreover, you will need to define a classless controller with the following defintion: (assuming you also are using Spring MVC with Webflow)

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/index.jsp" />
```

I think it's less cryptic to define intercept,forward,routing, etc... rules all in Spring Security config that way it is clear that any such rules are stored in one place.

Note: you might be able to keep your current setup and use that spring `<mvc:view-controller path="/index.jsp" />` definition only to trigger the JSF to execute.